# Cairo: Как задать RGB в cairo_set_source_rgb

Tags: c

На сайте cairo в описании к этой функции сказано:

> The color components are floating point numbers in the range 0 to 1.

(https://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html#cairo-set-source-rgb)

Как это понять? Например как мне задать цвет в RGB(113, 208, 113) в этой самой "range 0 to 1"?

Comment: Не работал с таким, но логика подсказывает что как то так `float_rgb_component = int_rgb_component / 255`

Comment: @Flowneee Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение это применить такую формулу:

```
float_rgb_component = int_rgb_component / 255.0
```

**P.S.** Перенесено из комментариев, чтобы легче было найти ответ

Comment: На самом деле - на 255.0, иначе будет выполнено целочисленное деление и вы получите нули...

Comment: @Harry поправил

Comment: А я в дабл кастил.